# MySQL: concurrent insert

Tags: mysql, concurrency, sql-insert

My MySQL configuration is set to use InnoDB storage.

I have 1 table called test1, with fields:

```
ID (auto increment), textcontent(varchar 200), SOURCE (varchar 50).
```

I have 2 programs, each one is inserting records into this MySQL table. Using similar SQL insert statement. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO test1 (textcontent, SOURCE) VALUES ('some text', 'program 1');
```

The source field indicate where the insert statement is from (so it's either program 1 or program 2).

If I kick off both program 1 and program 2 and they are basically inserting into mySQL server at the same time. What I found is that: there are some records not inserted for some reason.

For example, if program 1 supposed to run insert 3000 times, and program 2 supposed to run insert 4000 times. I would expect the total records in test1 table to be 3000+4000 = 7000. However, at the end, I got around 5000+

What's wrong? do I not configure MySQL correctly so it appears that some records are not inserted for some reason.

Comment: Any takers for the question. My main concern is that some records were missing. Not sure if it's a limitation to MySQL or I did something wrong, like configure MySQL server incorrectly...

Comment: I should add (that I forgot) to mentioned that my database server is actually MariaDB (not mySQL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the concurrent insert is ok, except that auto incrementing ID are not consecutive.